# Simulating AJAX with pure ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, api

This article helped me a lot regarding this question. I recommend it
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/Asp-Net-mvc-ajax-helper/

---

I have an upcoming task for university.The objectives is to design an API that holds the system logic which an web and android agents can use by requesting through URLs.

**What do I need ?**
As mention in the question title I need to update the contents of the view without the need to use AJAX/JQuery "not a mandatory prerequisite in the task but i have to ,As deadline around the corner hence no time to learn those"

**What did I try?**
I was thinking about using a C# Threading object i.e "System.Threading.Timer" to call the API every x seconds to detect changes and write to the view.
Everything was going well until I tried to write the changes to the view. I always encounter *System.Argument Exception : Value did not fall within the expected range*. After some looking, this exception is caused when it is tried to write to the view after it is already loaded. Here is the code

**User.cs**

```
public class User
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

**_Card.cshtml**

```
@model String
<!--dummy card design-->
<span>@Model</span><br>
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model List<User>
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
//Consider @Model = new List<User>(){new User(1,"User1"),new User(2,"User2")}
@foreach (User user in Model) { @Html.Partial("~/Views/z.Shared/Components/Cards/_Card.cshtml", user.Id + "         " + user.Name); }

<div id="newUsers">
    @{
        int existingUsersCount = Model.Count();
        void callable()
        {
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            String url = "apiURL";
            byte[] response = wc.DownloadData(url);
            String encodedResponse = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);
            //Consider encodedResponse = [{"Id":3,"Name":"newUser1"},{"Id":4,"Name":"newUser2"}]
            List<User> users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(encodedResponse);
            int newRecordsCount = users.Count() - existingUsersCount;
            if (newRecordsCount > 0)
            {
                List<User> newUsers = users.Skip(existingUsersCount).ToList();
                foreach (User user in newUsers)
                {
                    //Problem is here i cant write the changes to the view 
                    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/z.Shared/Components/Cards/_Card.cshtml", user.Id + "         " + user.Name);               
                    //Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Web.dll
                    //An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Web.dll
                    //Value does not fall within the expected range.
                }
                existingUsersCount+=newRecordsCount;
            }
        }
    }
</div>
@{
    var timer = new System.Threading.Timer((e) => callable(), null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
}
```

**Remarks on the code**

- From where does the thread take its resources from the server machine or browser machine ?

Comment: So on what line does the exception occur ?

Comment: @auburg I was assuming the line that starts with "//Poroblem is here..."

Comment: @itsme86 Doh ! Evidently not paying attention

Comment: @auburg as <itsme86> addressed after the comment problem is here
@Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/z.Shared/Components/Cards/_Card.cshtml", user.Id + "         " + user.Name);
                }

Comment: Does this work: @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/z.Shared/Components/Cards/_Card.cshtml", user.Id + "         " + user.Name);} (note the curly braces enclosing the RenderPartial call)

Comment: @auburg the 'a' was a typo. i believe you dont need it because you are already within a razor code. i used RenderPartial as it writes to the view directly instead of Partial that returns html string

Comment: You cannot update your view using c# code after it has been rendered and sent to the client(browser). After this point you can only run javascript code which will be executed on browser. For sending requests to the server I would recommend to use fetch API: it should be quite straightforward for beginners and there's no need to include any third-party libraries.

Comment: @RomanKoliada that's a bad news. i suspected that as well. Is fetch API a thing in c# or javascript ? as i am not familiar with it.

Comment: Sorry, it's javascript: https://javascript.info/fetch . I'm afraid the only way to run c# code on the client side is to use Blazor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/?view=aspnetcore-3.1 But it's in preview and available only for latest .net core